# How can i split the values in the column as per the image attached with spaces in pandas-python

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, data-science

I have a data set with raw data in a file in `.txt` format, lots of values in a single column.

I would like to split the 6 values, individual split into separate columns.

```
index
0     1 1 
1     2
2     3 2 2 4 2 2 2 3 3 (single column)
3     5
4     1
5     6
6     6 7 7 7 6 6 8 8 8 8 (single column)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split may be helpful.

Comment: please can you explain ,m new to python

Comment: could you show an example on how the content of the file looks?

Comment: i cannot upload image let me try to explain
imagine excel
o    
1   1 1
2      2
3       322456843

this is how it looks

Comment: dont upload an image, edit your original post and copy&paste a small, representative portion of the file content.

Comment: did you got it ?

Comment: What we need is a _verbatim_ copy of the file, and what you want as output.

Comment: yes values (12345678) is in single column but i want to have it in separate columns like 
col1 -1
col2-2

Comment: I did it now I have to make the pairing of values in particular column like 3 2 2 4 2 2 to [3,2][2,2][2,4][4,2][2,2] in whole of the data set

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`str.split()` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) of a Series (column) to split a string into multiple words, possibly turning them into separate columns.

You can use something like:

```
df = series.str.split(expand=True)
```

Or, assuming they're in a column named "values" (you don't seem to mention a column name and not sure how you're reading your `.txt` file):

```
df = df["values"].str.split(expand=True)
```

Your columns will be named with numbers starting at 0.

Your data in the columns will still be stored as strings. If you want, you can then convert those to integers (or floats), though if you want integers, you will probably need to handle the missing values in columns, by replacing them with a sentinel value such as 0 or -1.

For example, to use integers and set 0 for columns with no value:

```
df = df.fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Comment: I tried but the dataftame is too long so it was giving me a memory issue 10.2 gb

Comment: I did it now I have to make the pairing of values in particular column like 3 2 2 4 2 2 to [3,2][2,2][2,4][4,2][2,2] in whole of the data set 

Can you please tell me how will it pr possible

Comment: @P_data Please don't ask questions in comments. Post a new question if you have one. Be very specific about what you have and what you need. Also show what you have tried and how it doesn't work or how it doesn't do what you want. If this answer helped you, please upvote it and accept it if it answered this part of your issue, helping you make progress.

Comment: Ok sorry I am new to python and here also don’t know about it , thanks it helped